# Get list of managed pages

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm trying to get the list of pages a user manages.

The FB documentation for v2.12 says that I should use GetGraphNode().

```
try {
  // Returns a `FacebookFacebookResponse` object
  $response = $fb->get(
    '/{user-id}/accounts',
    '{access-token}'
  );
} catch(FacebookExceptionsFacebookResponseException $e) {
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(FacebookExceptionsFacebookSDKException $e) {
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}
$graphNode = $response->getGraphNode();
```

When I try this, I get an exception : "Unable to convert response from Graph to a GraphNode because the response looks like a GraphEdge. Try using GraphNodeFactory::makeGraphEdge() instead."

I tried $pages=$response->makeGraphEddge(); but this doesn't work.

Any idea ?

Thank you.

Comment: FOUND ! $pages =  $fb->get('/me/accounts', $accessTokenLong)->getGraphEdge()->asArray();

Comment: create an answer then and accept it. don´t leave this unanswered.