# facebook-php-sdk get user page data php-sdk

Tags: php, laravel, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.0

Using the facebook php sdk, am trying to retrieve all my pages with data like "name, website, decription..."

1. I used the facebook javascript api to login (I've asked for the required permissions) and retrieved the user token

```js
$fb = new \Facebook\Facebook([
'app_id' => $app_id,
'appsecret_proof' => $appsecret_proof,
'app_secret' => $app_secret,
'default_graph_version' => 'v5.0',
]);
$pagesResponse = $fb->get('/me/accounts', $access_token);
$pages_php=[];
$pagesEdge = $pagesResponse->getGraphEdge();
$pagesDecoded = json_decode($pagesEdge);
foreach ($pagesDecoded as $page) {
        $id=$page->id;
        $response = $fb->get(
            '/'.$id.'/locations?fields=name%2Cbio%2Cdescription',
            $access_token
        );
        //the following line returns an error 'Unable to convert response from Graph to a GraphNode'
        //$graphNode = $response->getGraphNode(); 
 //the following line return an array containing only the request without page data
        $graphNode = $response->getGraphEdge(); 
}
```

2. then I retrieved the page ID's I am managing but when I try to get the page data using the /{page-id}/locations endpoint the getGraphNode returns an error so I used getGraphEdge /{page-id}/locations endpoint it returns an array without the page data

```html
Facebook\GraphNodes\GraphEdge::__set_state(array(
   'request' => 
  Facebook\FacebookRequest::__set_state(array(
     'app' => 
    Facebook\FacebookApp::__set_state(array(
       'id' => '******************',
       'secret' => '******************',
    )),
     'accessToken' => '****************************************',
     'method' => 'GET',
     'endpoint' => '/{page-id}/locations?fields=name%2Cbio%2Cdescription%2Cwebsite',
     'headers' => 
    array (
      'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    ),
     'params' => 
    array (
    ),
     'files' => 
    array (
    ),
     'eTag' => NULL,
     'graphVersion' => 'v5.0',
  )),
   'metaData' => 
  array (
  ),
   'parentEdgeEndpoint' => NULL,
   'subclassName' => NULL,
   'items' => 
  array (
  ),
));
```

Comment: And – have you tried to do what the error message told you …?

Comment: This line triggers the error $response->getGraphNode()

Comment: This is the exact same as the documentation! but it seems like the sdk is returning a graph edge and not a graph node, so am unable to retrieve the page data (name location..)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50659248/get-list-of-managed-pages

Comment: thanks for your response, yes I got the managed pages id's
$pagesResponse = $fb->get('/me/accounts', $access_token);
$pages_php=[];
$pagesEdge = $pagesResponse->getGraphEdge();
this doesn't return all the required fields like the page website, page description...
to do so I needed to call the  /{page-id}/locations endpoint and this is expected to return a graph node, but it's actually returning a graph edge! so the page data is still not accessible!

Comment: _“and this is expected to return a graph node, but it's actually returning a graph edge!”_ - and? Handle it like an edge then, where is the problem with that?

Comment: it doesn't return the required data as a graph edge

Comment: What does that _mean_? What happens instead?

Comment: it return data like: endpoint:myendpoint and some futile data that doesn't meet the required data set within the endpoint url!

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by that. Please update the question, and include some debug output or a screenshot or something.

Comment: I've just updated the question, facebook stopped working for a while so it took time to update the question and show you the output!

Answer (score 0):

To get the pages data you need to use: '/user_id/accounts?fields=name,website,.." I was omitting the fields get parameter from the /accounts endpoint.